# Writing multiple lists of tuples side-by-side to CSV in Python

Tags: python, list, csv, row

After I've appended my data into each list I have a set of lists that look like this after I print(i,j,k):

```
print(i) = [('Danny', 'US', '1995')]
print(j) = [('290', 'Technology')]
print(k) = [('Winter', 'Corporate', '90', '20009')]
```

Seems simple enough but if I do this:

```
writer.writerow(i + j + k)
```

My output looks like:

```
      column 1                   column 2                       column 3

('Danny', 'US', '1995)   ('290', 'Technology')    (Winter', 'Corporate', '90', '20009)
```

However, I **want** to use *writerow* to take all of these lists and write them to CSV *side-by-side* with no brackets or quotations where every element in each list is in their own column like so:

```
Danny  US  1995  290  Technology  Winter  Corporate  90  20009
```

I can get each list to write in their own columns using *writerows(i + j + k)* but then each list is written underneath one another and not side-by-side.

My *minimized but complete program* looks like so:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_string, "lxml")

with open('./output.csv', 'ab+') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f, dialect = 'excel')

  for info in data:
    i = []
    j = []
    k = []

    for item1 in p:
      i.append(....stuff with Danny)

    for item2 in b:
      j.append(....things with 290)

    for item3 in n:
      k.append(....info with Winter)

    writer.writerow(i + j + k)
```

Comment: If `i`, `j`, and `k` are tuples, then `i + j + k` should also be a tuple, and `writerow` should write separate columns... right?

Comment: But it didn't, so they aren't. Maybe `i`, `j`, `k` are strings?

Comment: @HelloToEarch, please reduce your program to the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the problem. Please copy-paste that short program into your question, along with your actual and expected output. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: I have added what I feel to be complete yet minimal in my above edit!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be working, as I can't see your full source, here is a similar example that generates a row out of your tuples correctly.

```
i = ('Danny', 'US', '1995')
j = ('290', 'Technology')
k = ('Winter', 'Corporate', '90', '20009')


import csv

with open('eggs.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow(i+j+k)
```

**Csv Output:**

[image]

Comment: With this I now obtain my first column as |('Danny' with my second and third being 'US' and '1995'|

Comment: The colums are `Danny  US  1995  290  Technology  Winter  Corporate  90  20009` are you saying you are executing my code and you are not seeing the same

Comment: Sorry yes what I meant is that I am not seeing the same. I am now seeing `|('Danny'  'US'  '1995')|  |('290'  'Technology')|  |('Winter'  'Corporate'  '90'  '20009')|`

Comment: That's how your CSV file look like, when you open it in a text editor `Danny,US,1995,290,Technology,Winter,Corporate,90,20009` having `comma` as the separators. Tested in Python3 and Python2

Comment: Well when I open it in Excel it gives me the format I gave above.

Comment: Something must be wrong... make sure you are checking the file in a text editor and opening that file and not accidentally an older one.

Comment: I'm creating new files and the output is still the same. There may be a chance I have made a tuple of tuples or a list of tuples, though? I'm just really confused still on the format I'm getting from these XML files. I've parsed through each tag and sent every element I found as a _.text_ to append to each empty list as. Would that have any implications?

Comment: What you are appending is probably a list of tuples and not list as you stated. do `i.append(yourelement[0])` to see if this fixes

Comment: Yes it is a list of tuples. Very strange that printing my second set of data it shows as [('Danny', 'US', '1995')] now. My original appending looks like `i.append((name, country, date))` and when I use i.append((name, country, date)[0]) it gives me of course just the "name" as `print(i) = ['Danny']`

Comment: user1767754's code, which I cut and pasted, is working fine when I test it, it writes the columns correctly to csv which, when viewed in excel 2013. It will, of course, overwrite the previous data each time you open the csv to write in it. To solve this, you need to change the write mode from 'w' to 'a+'. I am adding an answer showing an alternative way of achieving the same thing.

Comment: Yes it should work for a set of tuples, however, my data is slightly different but in the form of a list of tuples. I've made the changes above to reflect this. Sorry for any miscommunication as I did not realize the format and simply assumed it was a list based off what I originally saw.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
import csv

i = ('Danny', 'US', '1995')
j = ('290', 'Technology')
k = ('Winter', 'Corporate', '90', '20009')

with open('./output.csv', 'a+', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, dialect = 'excel')

    i1=tuple()
    j1=tuple()
    k1=tuple()

    for item1 in i1:
    i = i+(item1,)

    for item2 in j1:
        j = j+(item2,)

    for item3 in k1:
        k = k+(item3,)

    dannyData = i+j+k
    print(dannyData)
    writer.writerow(dannyData)
```